# Simplifying $R_1R_2R_3 + R_1R_2R_4 + R_1R_3R_4 + R_2R_3R_4$ pattern

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Consider this sum of inverses:

$$\frac{1}{f_n} = \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{R_{n}}$$

The sum can be "simplified" with summation symbol:

$$\frac{1}{f_n} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{R_{i}}$$

I want to compute $f$ and express the above formula in terms of summation symbol(s).

Consider $n = 3$ case:

$$\begin{align*}f_n &= \frac{R_1R_2 + R_1R_3 + R_2R_3}{R_{1}R_{2}R_{3}} \\ &= \frac{\color{red}{?}}{\prod_{i=1}^n R_i}\end{align*}$$

I am not sure how to express the $\color{red}{?}$ numerator in terms of, probably, summation symbol(s).

There is a pattern for sure.

Consider $n = 4$:

$$f_n = \frac{\overbrace{\overbrace{R_{1}R_{2}R_{3}}^{n-1 \text{ terms}} + \overbrace{R_{1}R_{2}R_{4}}^{n-1 \text{ terms}} + \overbrace{R_{1}R_{3}R_{4}}^{n-1 \text{ terms}} + \overbrace{R_{2}R_{3}R_{4}}^{n-1 \text{ terms}}}^{n \text{ terms}}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} R_{i}}$$

Would anyone be able to help me formalize this numerator for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Comment: You can't simplify much. This is related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: This is one of the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), $e_3(R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4)$

Comment: Thanks, checking it now.

Comment: For the special case of $e_{n-1}(R_1,R_2,\dots,R_n)$ you might also choose to write this as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n R_j$ or something similar where the product ranges over all indices except $i$.  I seem to recall an author (*I think Hatcher*) using a caret notation as well to indicate a missing term in a product.

Comment: Denote $[n] = \{k \in \mathbb{Z}: 1\le k \le n\}$.

Another notation (similar to the one JMoravitz uses), you can also write:

$$\sum_{A\subset [n] \\ |A| = n-1}\prod_{a\in A}R_a$$